# Assign value or delete rows conditionally on two columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, transform

I just merged longitudinal data in R and discovered a problem. My dataframe, df, looks (roughly) like this:

```
Clinic   ID   Year    Result  
A         1   2000        50
A         1   2002
A         1   2004     
A         2   2000      
A         2   2002      
A         2   2004      1100
B         1   2000
B         1   2002
B         1   2004
```

We need all years of data for patients with test results and a way of assigning the Result value to all rows for that patient. I need to discard patients for whom no result was ever recorded. In this example I would need to keep all rows for patients 1 and 2 at clinic A, but discard all rows for patient 1 at clinic B. Further, at clinic A I would need all of patient 1's rows to list "50," as that was his test result.

I think ultimately I could use: df[!is.na(df$Result),]... but I can't figure out how to get the 'Result' value shared to all the relevant rows before deleting the NAs.

```
df <- transform(df, NewResult = (Clinic, ID, Fun=Function(Result) ifelse(Result>0 == Result, NA))
```

This did not work; it returned an error. Guidance greatly appreciated.

What I need is:

```
Clinic   ID   Year    Result  
A         1   2000        50
A         1   2002        50
A         1   2004        50
A         2   2000      1100
A         2   2002      1100
A         2   2004      1100
B         1   2000        NA
B         1   2002        NA
B         1   2004        NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `na.locf` from `zoo` to fill the NA values with non-NA values after grouping by 'Clinic' and 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, Result := na.locf(na.locf(Result, na.rm = FALSE), 
                        fromLast=TRUE, na.rm = FALSE), .(Clinic, ID)]
```

---

Or we can use `fill` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(Clinic, ID) %>% 
   fill(Result) %>%
   fill(Result, .direction = "up")    
#   Clinic    ID  Year Result
#   <chr> <int> <int>  <int>
#1      A     1  2000     50
#2      A     1  2002     50
#3      A     1  2004     50
#4      A     2  2000   1100
#5      A     2  2002   1100
#6      A     2  2004   1100
#7      B     1  2000     NA
#8      B     1  2002     NA
#9      B     1  2004     NA
```

Comment: The na.locf worked! I couldn't get the tidyverse fill to work though, but the first one solved my problem. Many thanks!